# How do I solve $(1/4)^{x+1}+(1/4)^x=20$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, factoring

I already know that I'm supposed to get is $5/4(1/4)^x$ after factoring, but I have absolutely no idea how to get there.

Here's what I've done thus far,

$(1/2^2)^{x+1}+(1/2^2)^x$

Not sure from there what to do; any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
(1/4)^{x+1}+(1/4)^x&=&20\\
(1/4)^x(1/4)^1+(1/4)^x&=&20\\
(1/4)^x(1/4+1)&=&20\\
(1/4)^x(5/4)&=&20\\
(1/4)^x&=&80/5\\
\log_2\left((1/4)^x\right)&=&\log_2(16)\\
x\log_2(1/4)&=&\log_2(16)\\
x&=&\frac{\log_2(16)}{\log_2(1/4)}\\
x&=&\frac{\log_2(2^4)}{\log_2(2^{-2})}\\
x&=&-\frac{4}{2}=-2
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How'd you do the first step? Can you clarify>

Comment: @Krish Ahluwalia  From $(1/4)^{x+1}+(1/4)^x=20$ follows $(1/4)^{x}(1/4)+(1/4)^x=20$ and $(1/4)^x(1/4+1)=20$, ok?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to this -- how did you go from (1/4)^(x+1) to (1/4)^x(1/4)?

Comment: @Krish Ahluwalia Because $y^{a+b}=y^a y^b$, so $(1/4)^{x+1}=(1/4)^{x}(1/4)^{1}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have, on the left hand side, $$\left(\frac 14\right)^{x+1}\cdot\left(\frac 14\right)^x$$

$$ = \left(\frac 14\right)^x\cdot \left(\frac 14 + 1\right)= \frac 54 \left(\frac 14\right)^x = 20 \iff \left(\frac 14\right)^x = 16 \iff 4^{-x} = 16$$

Now take $\log_2$ of each side.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate $\left(\frac14\right)^x \Rightarrow\left(\frac14\right)^x(\frac14+1) = \left(\frac14\right)^x\cdot\frac54 = 20$

So, $4^{-x} = 16$. Now, $x =?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=(\frac{1}{4})^x$

$\frac{5y}{4}=20$

$y=16$

$(\frac{1}{4})^x=16=(\frac{1}{4})^{-2}$

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted, looks good to me...

Comment: @Mike I agree - this is how I would have done it - use a substitution to make something which looks complicated rather more simple and then unwind it at the end. There may be more direct ways of proceeding, but if you are confused about a problem or with notation, simplifying in this way is a recommended strategy.